# Flash Player Already Installed

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, flash-player

I'm using windows 10 and google chrome.
I have not installed flash player,so why in the control panel appear the flash icon ?

[image: The Italian-language Windows 10 Control Panel showing "Flash Player (32 bit)" applet]

Answer (score 0):

- Windows 10 comes bundled with Adobe Flash Player for Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer. This bundling started in Windows 8.
- Google Chrome comes integrated with its own Adobe Flash Player.
- You can still download Adobe Flash Player for Firefox, Opera or Chromium on Windows 10. See https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/